# Breakpoint "concurrency" in Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, concurrency, ide

Lets say I have a class that initiates two threads **Thread_A** and **Thread_B**, each doing some calculations and ocassionally using a subroutine of my the class. (don't worry about data sharing, lets say it's a log line or imagine the subroutine is a method in a Java library) I want to know if there is a way of conditioning a breakpoint inside this subroutine to the subroutine having been called from say **thread_A**, but not B, or say a certain breakpoint having been hit prior to this breakpoint.

Obviously I can always go tho the frames tab in the debug window and see the caller thread, but it is tedious. It might be the case that **thread_A** accesses the subroutine much less often than **thread_B**. I don't want to have to see all the breakpoints which are initiated by **Thread_B**.

The way I currently do it, is setting up global flag variables and manipulating them just before calling the routine. I then have my breakpoint's condition depened on the flag variable. However that is probably not very thread-safe and not very clean.

What is the correct way of doing this? Out of curisoity, is there any other IDE for any other language that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the code that spwaned the threads your's ?
if so you could set unique names on the threads and use those names to
distinguish your threads when using breakpoint conditions.

e.g.

```
//spwaning the thread
Thread threadA=...
threadA.setName("thread-A");

// IntelliJ
Condition : Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("thread-A")
```

Comment: I see yeah that would work. The problem is that, yes the code is mine as in I have access to it, but this was a simplified version of the code. In reality this is me trying to understand someone else's code and if i knew what thread is what, the problem was a non-issue! :)

Comment: do your threads happen to already have names that can be used as an 'ID' ... if threads are started without giving them an explicit name a unique name will be generated.

i currently don't have access to a running IntelliJ ... but the frames tab shoud show something like "Thread[TheThreadsName,0,]" for each running thread ... so if your threads have unique names you should be able to see which names they have by looking at the frames tab and build a breakpoint condition using that

Comment: ha yeah that would do.